# Change ordering of fields of custom post type in admin page

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I have a custom post type and am placing in custom meta boxes.  How do I change the ordering of the fields of a custom page in the admin?

For example, I have a custom field called subtitle.
How do I place this between the title and description rich textbox in the admin of the custom post type page?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, really. When setting your boxes you can determine whether they appear below the post editor or on the side, and what their order is, but the title field and post editor are fixed in their location.

Comment: Well, I guess you can place anything anywhere you want using some Javascript to change the DOM of the page, but that would probably not be so future-proof.

Comment: @Jan in theory, yes, but then you're most likely getting into changing core files.

Comment: Hmm, I think it should be possible with an extra JS file. Now you got me intrigued, I'll try whether I can achieve it!

Comment: It should be possible as well by just sorting the array that lines the boxes up. That would be possible as a plugin on the server-side so no need to mess with Javascript. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

use this http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/ (amazing!!) and set your metabox to

```
'hide_title' => true,
'view' => WPALCHEMY_VIEW_ALWAYS_OPENED,
'lock' => WPALCHEMY_LOCK_AFTER_POST_TITLE
```